# Running elevated Powershell by script is not working

Tags: powershell

My Powershell script starts with the check if PS is running in elevated mode, if not it starts itself again in elevated mode. At my system it is running without problems. At another system the second shell starts and dies after a second. 
Does someone know this problem or could give me a hint how to trouble shoot. No anti virus is active and execution policy is set by group policy.

Here is the code (found somewhere on SO):

```
If (-NOT ([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator"))
{
    Write-Host "Running elevated..."
    $arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
    Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList $arguments
    Break
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is to add `-noexit` parameter to your arguments. You can do it like this:

```
$arguments = "-noexit & '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'"
```

It might also happen that you don't need `$myinvocation.mycommand.definition` part (this would only execute the same command once again in new window so it's not quite necessary). In that case you can just use:

```
$arguments = "-noexit"
```

or remove the variable and use this parameter directly:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList '-noexit'
```

#### Troubleshooting

Also, if you wanted to troubleshoot the initial code you had, you could use:

```
$arguments = "& '" + $myinvocation.mycommand.definition + "'; pause"
```

In case there's any error it'll be visible in your screen as `pause` waits until you press `Enter`.

#### Edit:

As mentioned by [Rohin Sidharth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51099841/9902555), `-noexit` is not necessary so the command might be just like:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs
```

This doesn't apply to the situation when `powershell.exe` is executed with command like that:

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs -ArgumentList 'Write-Host "test"'
```

as it'll close the window after execution.

Comment: Thank you, with the parameter

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: It was a mapped drive, which wasnt mapped in PsDrive. Now it works.

Comment: Not really sure how it's related with my answer - if you want to explain how you resolve it in separate answer, feel free to unmark this one and mark yours as accepted. Anyway, I'm glad it's resolved!

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the arguments at all. This is enough.

```
Start-Process powershell -Verb runAs
```